# Class type property breaks wired event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, events, properties

I have struggled with this for almost a day now, and have boiled it down to the following:

I have a UserControl called MyUserControl:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
…
```

This UserControl has one property called Property1:

```
public MySubClass Property1 {get; set;}
```

As you see the property is of type MySubClass which is a class defined as seen here:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MySubClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Declare event fired when a property has changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _subClassProperty1;

    public double SubClassProperty1
    {
        get
        {
            return _subClassProperty1;
        }
        set
        {
            _subClassProperty1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); //Call method to raise event
        }
    }

    //Raises the PropertyChanged event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged; //Copy event handler to temporary variable to make it thread safe
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(""));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this class contains an event that is fired when a property has been changed inside the class (in this case only one property exists: SubClassProperty1).

In the constructor of the UserControl I subscribe to the event from the sub class to get notified when a property has been changed. The constructor looks like this:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Property1 = new MySubClass();

    //Wire event fired when a property has been changed in sub class
    Property1.PropertyChanged += MySubClass_PropertyChanged;
}
```

The method (located in the user control class) called when the event is fired looks like this:

```
//Fired when a property has been changed in the sub class
private void MySubClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Property changed");
}
```

**The problem is the following:**
When dragging the user control to a form and changing the property of the subclass (SubClassProperty1) the event is fired and the MessageBox shown (the change of the property value is done at design-time in the properties window of Visual Studio).
If I now rebuild the project (Build-> Rebuild Solution) the event binding that I do in the constructor is lost, so when changing the value of SubClassProperty1 (again at design-time) the event is no more fired.

If I make the setter of Property1 private like this:

```
public MySubClass Property1 {get; private set;}
```

the event binding is not lost when rebuilding the project, but now the value of SubClassProperty1 is not persisted (gets reset to the default value when rebuilding the project).

**Question:**
I am clearly missing something about how to correct implement a class type property, but what am I doing wrong?

To sum up: I want to be able to set the properties of the sub class through the user control class’ property from the properties window of Visual Studio, without loosing the event binding.

Comment: The first question is: why are you rebuilding the solution? And, what makes you expect the values from a previous run will be kept?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. I must rebuild the solution after e.g. making changes to a user control for these changes to take effect.

Comment: The value of a property normally persist after a rebuild. Imagine the text property of a label; that does not change back to "label1" after a rebuild...

Comment: Ok, I see now; you are setting the value of the property at design time, via Visual Studio, correct? If that's the case, then the event will only continue to be triggered if you change the value of the property during the execution of your program. Are you currently doing that? Can you show us the code for it?

Comment: I think I did not describe this clearly enough: the changes of the property I described are all done from the properties window in Visual Studio at design-time!

Comment: Well, that's the issue: application needs to be running for the event to be risen (after the initial one). You shouldn't be using the design window to set control values (unless they are constants, which they are not in this case).

Comment: As I always understood the PropertyChangedEventHandler is made for this kind of stuff. It also fires every time I change the property from the designer, not only the first time. It stops working only after a rebuild.

Comment: Actually, you are firing that event whenever the property is _set_ not when it is changed. It will fire even if you set it to its current value. I suggest that you take a look at how the designer would generate code for a similar situation with a Microsoft control. I think you'll find that the property is instantiated, and event wired, inside of `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: @John Saunders: I don't know which Microsoft control to look at, and where to look... I assume most properties that can be changed at design-time don't fire an event when changed?

Comment: Actually, I think most do. Look at the events for even a `Button` control, and you'll find a lot of somethingChanged events

Comment: OK, maybe you are right. How do I look into the code of e.g. a button?